# Create TFS Tasks For New PBI's

Tags: tfs

I am working with a team and have set up Team Foundation Server 2013. We have a number of tasks that we want to include for each PBI. This includes items such as Code Review, Technical Documentation, etc.

I am looking for a way that these can be created automatically to save time during our Sprint Planning sessions. I am happy to write a UI or console application to do this, but wondered if there is a better way of doing this.

I know that automatically adding tasks might not be the best way to do things, but these tasks are needed due to requirements that have been placed on the team and will be kept to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a server side event handler which listens for PBI creation and then creates the linked tasks.

Essentially you are creating a class that implements ISubscriber with a method called ProcessEvent which will do the creation and linking of the task Work Items. Drop the dll into:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins.

[Simple article to follow (2012 but concepts are the same in 2013)](http://vgaltes.com/index.php/2013/04/14/create-a-team-foundation-server-event-handler/)

Shai Raiten has a good (albeit a little old) blog on the TFS API to implement ProcessEvent.

[TFS API: Create Link Between Work Item](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the server side events for this as rerwinRR suggestions, but you can also create a work item control that does this work to stay more in control when these tasks are created.

In Team Services (the cloud version of TFS) we already allow you to create extensions which even better support that model of adding actions.

Another option is to use Excel to quickly create these tasks.